# Functions exported by 'react'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
```

How can i see all the functions which are exported by 'react' ?

I looked into the file `react.js` inside `node_modules/dist/react.js` but could not find any statement like `module.exports = PropTypes ;`...

Comment: React.PropTypes has moved into a different package since React v15.5. Please use the prop-types library instead. https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm checking old version of `react` (15.4.1) library.

It exports `./lib/React`.

`./lib/React.js` file has `module.exports = React;`

`React` object in the same file is defined as:

```
var React = {

  // Modern

  Children: {
    map: ReactChildren.map,
    forEach: ReactChildren.forEach,
    count: ReactChildren.count,
    toArray: ReactChildren.toArray,
    only: onlyChild
  },

  Component: ReactComponent,
  PureComponent: ReactPureComponent,

  createElement: createElement,
  cloneElement: cloneElement,
  isValidElement: ReactElement.isValidElement,

  // Classic

  PropTypes: ReactPropTypes,
  createClass: ReactClass.createClass,
  createFactory: createFactory,
  createMixin: function (mixin) {
    // Currently a noop. Will be used to validate and trace mixins.
    return mixin;
  },

  // This looks DOM specific but these are actually isomorphic helpers
  // since they are just generating DOM strings.
  DOM: ReactDOMFactories,

  version: ReactVersion,

  // Deprecated hook for JSX spread, don't use this for anything.
  __spread: __spread
};
```

Here I can see it contains `PropTypes` property, which can be imported with `import {PropTypes} from 'react'`.

---

NOTE:

> `React.PropTypes` has moved into a different package since React
>   v15.5. Please use the `prop-types` library instead.

Source: https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html